# How can I download AFPL Ghostscript?

Tags: download, ghostscript

I tried to open PDF-file with the XnView program. But I was asking to download AFPL Ghostscript for this goal.

Comment: Ghostscript has been released under the GPL (initially v2, now AGPL 3) since approximately 2003, the AFPL license was dropped entirely in around 2006, except for some fonts which are still licensed that way. If you really need a version of Ghostscript that old you may have considerable trouble finding it. Does the XnView program (or website) specify whet version it wants ?

Comment: Looking here https://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=41845 I see that the ChangeLog (2.49.4) mentions Ghostscript 9.53.3, so I imagine that you absolutely do not want AFPL Ghostscript, that version of Ghostscript is only licensed under AGPL. Possibly that's what you meant rather than AFPL.

Comment: Yes, but I pointed at the 2.49.4 version, and my main point was that AFPL Ghostscript (which must be at least 15 years old IIRC) isn't what the OP wanted. Whether they want 9.54 or 9.53.3 depends on the version they are of XnView they are using.